# How to get mailto on interactive grid in sql (apex oracle)

Tags: html, sql, oracle, oracle-apex

on column Kontakti there is email lets say info@example.com how to make in mailto in sql.and all others will appear in this section Kontakti so how to make them mailto

Answer (score 1):

Use appropriate HTML tag with the `mailto` keyword. For example:

```
SQL> with kontakti (ime, adresa) as
  2    (select 'Little', 'little@gamil.com' from dual union all
  3     select 'Foot'  , 'foot@hotmial.com' from dual
  4    )
  5  select ime,
  6    '<a href="mailto:' || adresa || '">Send email</a>' mailto
  7  from kontakti
  8  /

IME    MAILTO
------ ------------------------------------------------
Little <a href="mailto:little@gamil.com">Send email</a>
Foot   <a href="mailto:foot@hotmial.com">Send email</a>

SQL>
```

In Apex, you'll have to set "Escape special characters" to **No** for the `mailto` column.

Comment: I edited the initial post so how should i incorporate that code into my sql code? @Littlefoot

Answer (score 1):

Change the column Type to **HTML Expression**. Set the attribute **HTML Expression** on the column to:

```
<a href="mailto:&KONTAKTI!ATTR.">&KONTAKTI.</a>
```

(I'm assuming your column name is KONTAKTI).

Comment: That makes all things in column Send Mail as hyperlink i just want adress to become as hyperlink http://prntscr.com/t3jm7g so any mail in this column that appears i want to default they become mailto so you click on the mail itself info@example.com and then it opens your outlook or whatever

Comment: You can put whatever you like in the label for the link. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

With column Type as Plain Text > Column Formatting HTML Expression enter the following:

```
<a href="mailto:#Kontakti#">#Kontakti#</a>
```

Ensure under Security 'Escape special characters' is unselected

Comment: I've never used this specific stack but wouldn't unselecting "Escape special characters" allow an SQL injection?

Answer (score 0):

Interactive report can be used with link type column, Link type > URL, URL "mailto:#EMAIL#" no quotes.